# Emulator not switching to next activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am totally new to android programming. 
I am doing a simple app in which I show a splash screen and then show the login screen. The problem is the emulator doesn't go beyond the splash screen.
AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sanginfo.loginsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

LoginActivity:

```
package com.sanginfo.loginsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

CharSequence userName;
String  passWord;
Boolean rememberme;
EditText username, password;
CheckBox tempchkrememberme;
Button login;
private SharedPreferences objSP;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   /* if(objSP.getString("username", null) != null) {*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // UI elements gets bind in form of Java Objects
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    tempchkrememberme = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkrememberme);

    objSP = this.getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor objEditor = objSP.edit();
    rememberme = objSP.getBoolean("rememberme", false);

    if (rememberme == true){
    username.setText(objSP.getString("username", ""));
    tempchkrememberme.setChecked(true);}
    //objEditor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
    objEditor.commit();

    // now we have got the handle over the UI widgets
    // setting listener on Login Button
    // i.e. OnClick Event
    login.setOnClickListener(loginListener);  
}
//}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

 private OnClickListener loginListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor objEditor = objSP.edit();
//getting inputs from user and performing data operations
        userName=username.getText().toString();
        String strUsername = username.getText().toString();
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        tempchkrememberme = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkrememberme);

        if (userName.length()==0) {
            username.requestFocus();
            username.setError("Email is required.");
            return;
            }

            boolean  isEmailValid = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(userName).matches();
            if (isEmailValid==false){
            username.requestFocus();
            username.setError("Email invalid.");
            return;
            }


        if(password.getText().toString().length() == 0 ){
            password.requestFocus();
            password.setError( "Password is required." );
            return; 
        }

        if (tempchkrememberme.isChecked()) {
            objEditor.putBoolean("rememberme", true);
            objEditor.putString("username", strUsername);
            //objEditor.putString("password", password);
            objEditor.commit();


        } else {
            objEditor.clear();
            objEditor.commit();

        }



          if(username.getText().toString().equals("aditya@sanginfo.com") &&
                      password.getText().toString().equals("password")){
// responding to the User inputs
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

          }else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credentials!",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                           
    }
  };
}
```

Splash Class:

```
        package com.sanginfo.loginsample;

  import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.splash);
         Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void Run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    Intent openLoginActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(openLoginActivity);
                }
            } 
         };
         timer.start();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Console:

```
 [2013-09-24 15:02:58 - LoginSample] Android Launch!
 [2013-09-24 15:02:58 - LoginSample] adb is running normally.
 [2013-09-24 15:02:58 - LoginSample] Performing com.sanginfo.loginsample.Splash activity launch
 [2013-09-24 15:02:58 - LoginSample] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Nexus4'
 [2013-09-24 15:03:00 - LoginSample] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
 [2013-09-24 15:03:00 - LoginSample] Starting activity com.sanginfo.loginsample.Splash on device emulator-5554
 [2013-09-24 15:03:01 - LoginSample] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sanginfo.loginsample/.Splash }
[2013-09-24 15:03:01 - LoginSample] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

The last two in Red.

LogCat: (All Es in Red)

```
 .....
 09-24 14:16:37.892: I/System.out(904): Sending WAIT chunk
 09-24 14:16:38.122: I/dalvikvm(904): Debugger is active
09-24 14:16:38.142: I/System.out(904): Debugger has connected
09-24 14:16:38.152: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:38.352: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:38.552: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:38.752: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:38.962: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:39.162: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:39.362: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:39.562: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:39.762: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:39.963: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:40.172: I/System.out(904): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-24 14:16:40.373: I/System.out(904): debugger has settled (1416)
09-24 14:16:42.502: D/gralloc_goldfish(904): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:19:11.183: E/Trace(976): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:19:12.423: D/gralloc_goldfish(976): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:24:00.873: E/Trace(1024): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:24:02.053: D/gralloc_goldfish(1024): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:30:40.193: E/Trace(1070): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:30:41.653: D/gralloc_goldfish(1070): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:35:43.943: E/Trace(1117): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:35:45.383: D/gralloc_goldfish(1117): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:38:58.883: E/Trace(1191): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:39:00.453: D/gralloc_goldfish(1191): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:40:25.943: E/Trace(1237): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:40:27.145: D/gralloc_goldfish(1237): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:43:52.323: E/Trace(1309): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:43:53.143: D/gralloc_goldfish(1309): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-24 14:54:02.202: E/Trace(1358): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-24 14:54:03.993: D/gralloc_goldfish(1358): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: do you got any exception in the Logcat?

Comment: added the console... see Edit

Comment: Post the Logcat , not the Console.

Comment: change <action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY" /> to `<action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LoginActivity" />`

Comment: Shakeeb bhai did u check the console? The last one line is in Red...

Answer (score 0):

I think u have done wrong in intent-filter section
  First remove intent filter code in second activity and check the output and comment about it

Modify this line

```
 Intent openLoginActivity = new  Intent("com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY");
```

as

```
 Intent openLoginActivity = new  Intent("Splash.this","LOGINACTIVITY.class");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the intent using below constructor

```
  Intent it = new Intent(packageContext, cls);//
```

declare your intent like this

```
 Intent it = new Intent(splash.this, LOGINACTIVITY.class);//
```

constructor that you are using is for implicit intent which takes `action` as parameter and

change

```
  <action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY" />
```

to

```
   <action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LoginActivity" />
```

Comment: @stylojack_10 the class name which contains splash activty will become your context..eg if your class name is MainActivity then your packageContext is MainActivity.this

Comment: All my code is already posted... I think something is wrong in the manifest file.

Comment: add complete code of  manifest ,splashactivity and loginActivity

Comment: change <action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY" /> to `<action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LoginActivity" />`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at intent,Where you have to set the activity name at which you wants to go.

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),your class name here.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }
};th.start();
```

Comment: but you have placed some thing else like this:    Intent openLoginActivity = new  Intent("com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY");

Comment: have you update your manifest file:    <activity android:name=".here your new activity name"></activity>

Comment: no need to define the intent filter for each new activity again and again......its auto created.....only you have to change for new activity.

Comment: so which one should I remove?

Comment: last one that you have entered manually.You no need to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following code from your LoginActivity manifest.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sanginfo.loginsample.LOGINACTIVITY" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please rebuild your project and then perform a fresh install.